# send object/var from php server to app android

Tags: android

i have some trouble here with my server and app.. so i want to pass object/var from server with php..and i having trouble how to retrieve it.. in this case i want to pass id,username to my app..

this is my code **user.java**

```
public class User   {
   private String username="";  
   private String password="";  
   private int id;
}
```

on my login form, this is my code

```
void login(){
    try{            

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();

        httppost= new HttpPost("http://nervousme.vacau.com/check_login.php"); .

        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",et_username.getText().toString().trim()));  
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",et_password.getText().toString().trim())); 
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        response=httpclient.execute(httppost);


        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Login Berhasil")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginForm.this,"Login Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });

            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginForm.this,UserHome.class);
            intent.putExtra("username",et_username.getText().toString());  

            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            showAlert();                
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        dialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void showAlert(){
    LoginForm.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginForm.this);
            builder.setTitle("Login Gagal");
            builder.setMessage("Terdapat Kesalahan Pada Username/Password")  
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       }
                   });                     
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();               
        }
    });
}
```

then on my php server side :

```
$query_search = "select * from USER where username = '".$username."'
AND password = '".$password. "'";

$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec); //echo $rows;

if($rows == 0) { 
  echo "Login Gagal";   
}  else  {
  echo $username,$id;    
}
```

is it my code on php server correct? (just echo username and id). if my code correct then how to save username and id to my object(class)? if i just echo username,id then show it to textview and get the value and set it on my class, is it still object oriented ?my friend make me confuse about object oriented programming

any help will be appreciated..thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're handling the response on the Java side so its really up to you how to persist it. You could use the preferences classes or use an object relational mapper (orm) for sqlite3. Examples for both are easy to come by

Comment: if i just echo username,id then show it to textview and get the value and set it on my class, is it still object oriented ?my friend make me confuse about object oriented programming..

Comment: As long as it works the rest is style. Java is an object oriented language. That should be helping not getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest you to use JSON, you have it both in php and Android sdk, it will ease your life a lot.
Nevertheless it seems to me a bit strange how you're "parsing" the http response:

```
if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Login Berhasil")) { ... }
```

I don't see you server to return that...

You can have a look in the android samples, there are several examples on how to use JSON, for instance here: /android-sdk-macosx/samples/android-16/SampleSyncAdapter/src/com/example/android/samplesync/client/NetworkUtilities.java

Comment: yep, its because i've changed the response..

my friend suggest me use JSON too..but i a bit lazy to change the code..haha..